# How to traverse all nodes of a graph using DFS algorithm if the graph is not connected

Tags: algorithm, sorting, depth-first-search

What's the algorithm to traverse all the nodes of a graph if the graph is not connected? An explanation would be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One common strategy is to do something like this:

```
for each node in the graph:
    if we haven't yet explored it:
         run a DFS starting at that node
```

The idea is that each DFS will visit some cluster of nodes (a full connected component if the graph is undirected; the strongly connected component and all descendant SCCs if the graph is directed). The outer loop ensures that each node is eventually processed. You'll see this used in, for example, Kosaraju's algorithm for strongly connected components or a DFS-based topological sort.

This, of course, assumes the graph is given to you in a way where you can easily iterate over all nodes. If the graph is defined implicitly, then the process of generating all the nodes may be interesting in and of itself.